# 21.10 dual screen stopped working

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I'm running Xubuntu 21.10, with stock kernel (5.13.0-20) on ASUS motherboard.
Built-in Intel with DVI output, plus GeForce GT 430 card with HDMI.

I've had it set up for a long time with display :0.0 on the Intel DVI for my console, and display :0.1 on the GT430 HDMI, which is connected to my TV.  All worked fine until recently, when after a reboot there was no HDMI output, and in fact no display :0.1 at all.

I have scoured the web, and found many different answers, including using the NVIDIA driver, but nothing has worked.  Please help: my partner misses her TV!

xrandr shows just the console:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Relevant parts of /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "ViewSonic-console"
    VendorName      "ViewSonic"
    ModelName       "VX2439 Series"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Panasonic-TV"
    VendorName      "Panasonic"
    ModelName       "TH-42A410Z"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "IntelGPU-DVI"
    Driver          "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Asus-GT430-HDMI"
    Driver          "nouveau"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Screen-Console"
    Device          "IntelGPU-DVI"
    Monitor         "ViewSonic-console"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Screen-TV"
    Device          "Asus-GT430-HDMI"
    Monitor         "Panasonic-TV"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier      "Layout-normal"
    Screen          0               "Screen-Console"
    Screen          1               "Screen-TV"
    InputDevice     "Keyboard0"     "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice     "Mouse0"        "CorePointer"
EndSection
```

Outputs requested:

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 0

$ xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 0 x 0, current 1536 x 864, maximum 32768 x 32768
default connected primary 1536x864+0+0 406mm x 228mm
   1536x864       0.00*
```

Also, these lines from `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` may be relevant:

```
(II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Sat Jan 23 12:24:42 2021 -0500
(II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
...
    GeForce GTX 4xx/5xx (GFxxx)
...
(EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19
(EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19
(EE) No devices detected.
```

Comment: Could you provide `xrandr --listproviders` output? And also meaningful lines from `xrandr --query` output.

Comment: Further testing, including install clean OS, leads me to believe that the graphics card may well be dead. Will update when new one arrives.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be an intermittent fault on the TV, where it would sometimes fail to deliver the EDID, which led to wrong default display resolution, and ultimately failure to recognise that output altogether.  I worked round it by supplying a 'canned' EDID on the boot command line.